# Named function inside a Javascript object? Why does this work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, anonymous-function

I stumbled upon this by accident when writing some code:

```js
var obj = {
  myFunc() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
  }
};

obj.myFunc();
```

What I meant to type was this:

```
var obj = {
  myFunc: function() { 
    // ...
  }
};
```

I didn't notice I accidentally typed the first one until I realized my code wasn't running in IE11.

Why does the first example work in Chrome/Firefox, and not IE11?

Also, if this is an official language feature, **what is this called**?

Comment: Thanks, but add it as an answer.

Comment: "Why does the first example work in Chrome/Firefox, and not IE11?" — Because only two of those are modern browsers.

Comment: It is modern ECMAScript which is valid, but only on browsers that can parse it.

Comment: @Quentin : Isn't IE11 modern browser?

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 — No. It's the lumbering final form of a dead browser that was superseded by Edge almost two years ago.

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 no, it isn't. It's _more recent_ but not really "modern". As you can clearly see here it doesn't support ES6 nor will it ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an [Enhanced Object Literal](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals), which is es6 syntax. More formally, [Object Initializers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) allow [Method Definitions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions) instead of only key/value pairs as in previous versions.

[This table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) tells the compatibility story under 'object literal extensions'. The short answer is just that IE11 hasn't implemented that feature.